# Email Composer Plugin is not working on Android 6 (Marsh Mallow) with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer plugin for sending a email on Android with Cordova. But it is not working on Android 6 (MarshMallow) and it is working on below version of Android 6.

Comment: what error You are getting post your log... exactly what error you are facing... Post your log in android 6 and below android6.

Answer (score 2):

That's likely because the plugin requires the [GET_ACCOUNTS permission](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/blob/master/plugin.xml#L90) and the plugin has not added the runtime permission bits for Android M devices when building with SDK 23+.

You could use SDK 22 or lower instead of 23+ to build your app and runtime permissions won't be required.

Comment: You have identified the root cause, thanks. The best solution would be to modify the plugin or check permissions in the app. If I find how to do this I will post a link.